# Problem Of Lazy Fish

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, kinematics

Fish achieve neutral buoyancy (so they don't have to swim constantly to stay in place) via a swim bladder. A swim bladder is a little internal sack that they can inflate/deflate with air, which changes their volume but not their total mass. To see how this allows them to change their buoyancy, let's consider the situation of a fish floating at rest in the ocean at some arbitrary depth. It inflates its swim bladder and increases its volume to 1.1 times its original volume without losing any mass. It therefore should begin to accelerate upwards automatically without having to swim. What is its acceleration in $m/s^2$?

Comment: Instead of just posting all your homework questions here, try to show some effort in working out the problems so you can ask more specific questions about physics fundamentals...you will learn better that way

Comment: Additionally, this is a Brilliant.org message and has obviously been posted in attempts of cheating.

Answer (score 3):

From Archimedes' Principle we know the upthrust is equal to the weight of the displaced fluid. If a fish has neutral buoyancy, it means it is displacing a volume of water equal to its own weight:

$\rho_{water} V_{fish}=m_{fish}g_1$

In order to float it must therefore displace more water--by expanding.

$\rho_{water} V_{fish+++}=m_{fish}g_2$

When we divide the second equation by the first, we end up with

${V_{fish+++}\over V_{fish} } = \frac{g_2}{g_1}=1.1$

Acceleration due to gravity as perceived by the fish increased by 10%, similar to the felt increase in your own weight when inside an elevator accelerating upwards. So the upward acceleration of the fish is 10% of $g_1@9.8m/s^2$